# Undeclared identifier: TGMObjects running gmlib

Tags: delphi, gmlib

I have just download gmlib(v 1.1.0 final) with Delphi 2010. I have installed as per install.txt. I have problem running the demo.

I have tried creating a new VCL project and place only TGMMAP component on the forms, I get this error

Undeclared identifier: 'TGMObjects'.

Yes I did this

> Delphi 2010 Installation
>
> 1. Open the project "GMLibProject_D2010.groupproj"
> 2. Right click on "GMLib_D2010.bpl" and click "Compile" and "Install"
> 3. Go to "Tools > Options > Environment Options > Delphi Options > Library-Win32 > Library Path > [...]"
>      Browse to the "lib\D2010" folder and press "OK", "Add"
>      Browse to the "src" folder and press "OK", "Add"
>      Browse to the "src\VCL" folder and press "OK", "Add", "OK", "OK"

Any help appreciated

Comment: Please, download the latest version via SVN from http://code.google.com/p/gmlibrary/source/checkout

Comment: download thru svn same error,TGMMAP is version 1.2.0 final now

Comment: I have install on XE5, looks fine,  demo running, looking great

Comment: Perfect. It's possible that into 2010 you need to delete all files (sources and binaries) before install the newest version

Answer (score 0):

Version 1.1.0 is an old version.
Delete all current files. 
Install the lastest: GMLib 1.2.0 from http://code.google.com/p/gmlibrary/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk

Open and run the demo app. This should work.
You can find the installation instructions here: http://code.google.com/p/gmlibrary/source/browse/trunk/Install.txt